# Jquery on hover show additional information

Tags: jquery

I need a jquery that on hover show additional information about an employee these information must be retrieved from a database.Im using this one :

http://rndnext.blogspot.com/2009/02/jquery-ajax-tooltip.html

but this part of the code that it isn't working:

```
         $.ajax({  
         type: 'GET',  
         url: 'personajax.aspx',  
         data: 'page=' + pageID + '&guid=' + currentID,
```

if i put a sample html instead it works:

how the querystring shoul be written

Comment: How do you use it? Please post what you have done so far. This is not a coding service.

Comment: Which bit isn't working? do you get errors? is it specific parts of the code? or a specific case?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has syntax errors (parentheses are not closed). Plus it may be better to provide object instead of string, just for visibility purposes:

```
var pageID = ''; // your pageID
var currentID = ''; // your currentID
$.ajax({  
    type: 'GET',  
    url: 'personajax.aspx',  
    data: {'page': pageID, 'guid': currentID}
});
```

(of course assign correct `pageID` and `currentID` above)

This may solve your problems, but they may also be caused by the server-side script or some other problem within your script.

Comment: @sally If you use the same JavaScript code, you just replace `var pageID = '';` and `var currentID = '';` with proper assignments.

Comment: I just want to know what shoul I have in the personajax.aspx

Comment: @sally I do not know what you have in `personajax.aspx`. To process the data that has been sent, you have to just process GET parameters in a way you need. But this is probably what you already know, so what is really the question? I think I do not follow, be more descriptive.